# Add a button or radio box that update the user role

Tags: user-roles

I'm sorry for my english. In my site I've created a page list with all registered users and their role (Subscriber). This is the code

```
$args = array( 'role' => 'Subscriber' );

  $user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );
  if ( ! empty( $user_query->results ) ) {
  foreach ( $user_query->results as $user ) {
  echo '<p>' . $user->display_name . '</p>';
      foreach ( $user->roles as $role )
      echo $role;
  }
  } else {
      echo 'Nessun Utente trovato.';
  }`
```

what I would want to do is to insert for every user a button or a radio box that allows to update the role of the user to "author".

Appreciate your help...

Comment: when you go in the administration area you have already the user list and the edit page to update a user to another role.

Comment: I know it. But I don't want everything this to be effected in backend. I have created a page in frontend on which an administrator can have the possibility to change the role of an user as described in my question.